# JUDDI Authorization

Tags: apache, tomcat7, uddi, juddi

I would like to know about authorization in jUDDI. I would like to give Publisher capabilities to few of my clients And also I want few of my clients to inquire or access only those services which are related to them. I want to hide the rest of the services which are not related to them. Can we achieve this using jUDDI? and How?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, no. There is an open ticket for this to provide role, group, list, etc access control on a per record (business/service) basis but it hasn't been implemented.

This problem is also a complex one, since UDDI has both a search and a getDetails set of methods. Get Details in the easy one, but search is very complex. Filtering out records and keeping the paging option still functional would be a challenge